# How to save the variables into workspace or a file?

Tags: matlab, file, variables, save, workspace

I'm new in MATLAB, I have a code that runs another code throw a function. 
here is first code that runs second code:

```
function D=DataT3DSVFAE
%m number of elements
%n number of nodes
m=94;
n=38;
%coordinates of nodes [(X Y Z) for each node] 
Coord=[-299.1 200 1875; 25.8 200 1875;
425.8 200 1875; 425.8 -200 1875;
25.8 -200 1875; -299.1 -200 1875;
-327.9 251.7 1450; 25.8 251.7 1450;
425.8 251.7 1450; 425.8 -251.7 1450;
25.8 -251.7 1450; -327.9 -251.7 1450;
-356.6 303.4 1025; 25.8 303.4 1025;
425.8 303.4 1025; 425.8 -303.4 1025;
25.8 -303.4 1025; -356.6 -303.4 1025;
-390.4 364.2 525; 25.8 364.2 525;
425.8 364.2 525; 425.8 0 525;
425.8 -364.2 525; 25.8 -364.2 525; 
-390.4 -364.2 525; -390.4 0 525;
-425.8 423.9 25; 25.8 423.9 25;
425.8 423.9 25; 425.8 0 25;
425.8 -423.9 25; 25.8 -423.9 25;
-425.8 -423.9 25; -425.8 0 25;
-425.8 423.9 0; 425.8 423.9 0;
 425.8 -423.9 0; -425.8 -423.9 0];
 %conection of the nodes [first in coordinates is the first node and ...]
 Con=[1 2; 2 3; 4 5; 5 6; 3 4; 1 6; 2 5; 1 12; 6 7; 3 10; 4 9; 1 8; 2 8; 3 
 8;6 11; 5 11; 4 11; 1 7; 3 9; 4 10; 6 12; 7 8; 8 9; 10 11; 11 12; 7 12;...
 9 10; 8 11; 8 10; 7 18; 12 13; 9 16; 10 15; 8 13; 8 15; 10 17; 12 17; 7 
 13;9 15; 10 16; 12 18; 13 14; 14 15; 16 17; 17 18; 15 16; 13 18; 14 17; 14 
 16;13 26; 18 26; 15 22; 16 22; 13 20; 14 20; 15 20; 16 24; 17 24; 18 24; 13 
 19;15 21; 16 23; 18 25; 19 20; 20 21; 23 24; 24 25; 21 22; 22 23;...
 19 26; 25 26; 22 24; 20 26; 20 24; 26 27; 26 33; 26 34; 22 30; 22 29;...
 22 31; 20 29; 20 27; 20 28; 24 32; 24 31; 24 33; 19 27; 21 29; 23 31;...
 25 33; 27 35; 29 36; 31 37; 33];
 % Create storage for Q, V and R
 allQ = cell(2,1); 
 allV = cell(2,1);
 allR = cell(2,1);
 % Load has only a Fx and all other forces and moments are zero
 % uniform loads in local coordinate system
 w=zeros(m,3);
 % E: material elastic modules G:shear elastic modules J:torsional constant
 E=ones(1,m)*1e4;nu=0.3;G=E/(2*(1+nu));
 % A:cross sectional area and Iy Iz: moment of inertia
 A=ones(1,m)*0.5;Iz=ones(1,m);Iy=ones(1,m);J=ones(1,m);
 %St: settlement of supports & displacements of free nodes
 St=zeros(n,6); be=zeros(1,m);
 % All of the variables are transposed and stored in a structure array in 
 the 
 %name of D
 D=struct('m',m,'n',n,'Coord',Coord','Con',Con','Re',Re',...
 'Load',Load','w',w','E',E','G',G','A',A','Iz',Iz','Iy',...
 Iy','J',J','St',St','be',be');

 [allQ{t},allV{t},allR{t}]=MSA(D); % Save the results
```

This codes runs another code by the name of MSA(D) as a function.

The problem is that I can have the outputs in my workspace or inside a file or any variables. They just appear inside my command window and I can't use them for my further developments. **I need these variables inside a file or worksapce:**

```
 allQ = cell2mat(allQ)
 allV = cell2mat(allV)
 allR = cell2mat(allR)
```

**Any helps appreciated :)**

Comment: Why not just make them the outputs of `DataT3DSVFAE`?

Comment: Suppress printing on screen by ending the lines with a semicolon `;`. Also, read about the function `save` if you want them in a file.

Comment: Thanks excaza, but what you mean??

Comment: Ander Biguri Thank you. But using semicolon at the end of them stops the loop process which is not possible... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By default, variables will only appear in the workspace if they are the output of the function, whether you run your function from a main script or directly from your command window. I ran your function in the command window without the following line:

```
[allQ{t},allV{t},allR{t}]=MSA(D); % Save the results for Q, V and R
```

And the structure `D` appeared in the Workspace. Then I typed `D.m`, `D.n`, etc, to access other parts of the structure. Here is a picture:
[image: Code, Command Window, and Workspace]

Hopefully this helps..

Comment: Thank you Luis. There is a problem that we can't run the code without the line that you omitted! Because in this line we use the second function that you can find in the attachment! We run the first code then inside the first one the second code MSA(D) is called to do the main calculations but in each time step and at the end we put all of allQ allV and allR inside one cell by cell2mat! Also as you check even in your method allQ allV allR are all empty array and also inside D struc we don't have the parameters I need!

Comment: Why don't you include 'allQ', 'allV', and 'allR' in your struc? You are not outputting 'allQ', allV', and 'allR' in D. Either include these variables in the struc, or output them directly. For the second choice, instead of:

function D=DataT3DSVFAE 

you should have something like this: 

function [D,allQ, allV,allR]=DataT3DSVFAE. If you do this, you should see the D,allQ, allV,allR variables in the workspace.

Comment: More clearly: In addition to outputting your variables from the MSA function you have to do it again in your DataT3DSVFAE function because MSA is inside of DataT3DSVFAE.  Either include 'allQ', 'allV', and 'allR' in your struc or output them directly. To output them directly, instead of:
function D=DataT3DSVFAE 
you should have something like this: 
function [D,allQ, allV,allR]=DataT3DSVFAE. If you do this, you should see the D,allQ, allV,allR variables in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some variables in MATLAB that you want to save for the future there are two ways of doing this:

```
save('workspace1.mat')       % Will save all variables
save('workspace2.mat',X,Y,Z) % Will save the variables X, Y, Z
```

If you want to load them in the workspace again:

```
load('workspace1.mat')       % Loads the saved variables
```

For more complex things, I suggest you take a look at the documentation [(link)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#inputarg_variables)

Comment: Thanks xrr. But the problem is we dont access the variables inside the workspace!! And I dont know how to make them to be inside workspace!! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones help;
But I myself found the answer.

I write it for anyone who has problem in saving variables!
The question is:
The variables were just in access inside of command window of matlab and they were not inside of workspace! So for saving any variable inside of any workspace the function **assignin** can be used!
Further helps you can check assignin function inside matlab help :) have fun!